# Suggest a better way to organize the data using structures and classes

Tags: c++, class, data-structures, dataset

Here's a data table I'm supposed to use in my application. I am using C++ for my embedded application. I've a list of directories each containing multiple files (max 255). The names(strings) of these directories and the name of the files contain the timestamps of their creation, which is what I'm using to sort (by comparing the int values of) the files in the order of their creation time. Here's the table of data. What type of structures can I use here so that the code is easily readable and its easy to do remove/add entries ? (ignore the numbers in this table if it is confusing)

| DirNamesList (string) | ExtractInt(string) | ConvertToEpoch(int) | SortInAscendingOrder(int) | ConvertToDirName(string) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5102021_234523 | 5102021234523 | 1620690323 | 1620685353 | 5102021_222233 |
| 5102021_222233 | 5102021222233 | 1620685353 | 1620690323 | 5102021_234523 |

Now once these are created, I've each directory in the 5th column with multiple files as below..

| DirNamesList (string) | FilesName(string) | ConvertToEpoch(int) | SortInAscendingOrder(int) | ConvertToFileName(string) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5102021_222233 | abcd_5102021234524 | 1620690324 | 1620685353 | efgh_5102021234523 |
|  | efgh_5102021234523 | 1620690323 | 1620685354 | abcd_5102021234524 |
| 5102021_234523 | pqrs_5102021234523 | 1620690333 | 1620690333 | pqrs_5102021234523 |

and so on..

What are some other better and intuitive ways than a bunch of vector strings I can use here.?

Comment: Likely: `std::vector<MyStruct>` where MyStruct is a struct with one variable for each column